# Existing contents get deleted on Live Preview when adding new content on a matrix field

Tags: craft3, matrix, live-preview

When I add a new content for a matrix block field on an existing entry, all its previous contents gets deleted from the Live Preview, except for the editor which still has the previous contents. And then, when I try to save the entry, it seems that what is shown in the Live Preview was the only one saved and the previous data were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this problem in a multisite-installation? If so, it could be something with your propagation mode on the matrix field.

Please give us some more details to your setup: which version of Craft CMS, which propagation mode, multisite or not.